# Getting the SQL from a Doctrine Migration

Tags: sql, migration, doctrine

I have been researching a way to get the SQL statements that are built by a generated Migration file. These extend Doctrine_Migration_Base.  Essentially I would like to save the SQL as change scripts.

The execution path leads me to Doctrine_Export which has methods that build the SQL statement and executes them.  I have found no way of asking for just them.  The export methods found in Doctrine_Export only operate on Doctrine_Record models and not Migration scripts.

From the command line './doctrine migrate version#' the path goes:

- Doctrine_Cli::run(cmd)
- Doctrine_Task_Migrate::setArguments(args)
- Doctrine_Task_Migrate::execute()
- Doctrine_Migration::migrate(to)
- Doctrine_Migration_Process::Doctrine_Export::various
  create, drop, alter methods with sql
  equivalents.

Has anyone tackled this before?  I really would not like to change Doctrine base files. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking into account Rob Farley's suggestion, I modified:

- Doctrine_Core::migrate
- Doctrine_Task_Migrate::execute

When the execute method is called the optional argument 'dryRun' is checked.  If true
then a 'Doctrine_Connection_Profiler' instance is created.  The 'dryRun' value is then passed onto
the 'Doctrine_Core::migrate' method.  The 'dryRun' value of true allows the changes to rollback when done executing the SQL statements.  When the method returns, the profiler is parsed and non-empty SQL statements
not containing 'migration_version' are saved and displayed to the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Could you make a dev server, and do the migration on that, storing a SQL Trace as you go?you don't have to keep the results, but you would get a list of every command.

Comment: Interesting.  I will look into that and get back to you.  I feel I might have to modify the base Doctrine files anyway as their CLI implementation is lacking.  There is a dryRun option available that Doctrine_Task_Migrate doesn't even bother checking for.

Basically the 2 options I am going for are:
Add the dryRun option, run a migration with dryRun and SQL Trace to capture the statements.
Or
Along with the dryRun option, add another option to just output the
SQL statements, this would require a modified Doctrine_Migration_Process file, maybe I'll call it Doctrine_Migration_GetSQL.

Comment: Sounds valid. Certainly SQL Trace is a good way of getting the commands.